# HTML horizontal bar chart with a goal line?

Tags: html, graph, charts

Is there a library that handles drawing an HTML horizontal bar chart, but with a goal line included, so the gap between the progress and the goal can be seen? I'd call this a 'horserace bar chart', but apparently no one else does.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the library [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7a4hhzge/455/): Here is the jquery code to draw a horizontal line.

```
var data = {
    labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
    datasets: [{
        data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
    }]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("LineWithLine").getContext("2d");

Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineWithLine",
    initialize: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var point = this.datasets[0].points[this.options.lineAtIndex]
        var scale = this.scale
        console.log(this);

        // draw line
        this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.ctx.moveTo(scale.startPoint+12, point.y);
        this.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
        this.chart.ctx.lineTo(this.chart.width, point.y);
        this.chart.ctx.stroke();

        // write TODAY
        this.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        this.chart.ctx.fillText("TODAY", scale.startPoint + 35, point.y+10);
    }
});

new Chart(ctx).LineWithLine(data, {
    datasetFill : false,
    lineAtIndex: 2
});
```